# jemand anderen, jemanden anderes

Tags: word-choice

Welche von diesen dreien Varianten ist richtig?

> 1. Fragen Sie jemanden anders.
> 2. Fragen Sie jemand anderen.
> 3. Fragen Sie jemanden anderen.

Hat es etwas mit der Deklination von "jemand" zu tun?
Wie ist das es überhaupt richtig:

Nom.: jemand

Akk: jemand oder jemanden?

Dat.: jemand oder jemandem?

Gen.: jemandes

Oder sind beide Varianten der Deklination möglich?